# Como reseteo los datos de los streams en Dart(flutter)?

Tags: android, flutter, app, dart

Estoy creando una pequeña app y No se como eliminar los datos dentro de los streams. por ejemplo en el login relleno el usuario y el password e inicio session. y al cerrar session aun quedan los datos dentro de los streams y aparece activo mi boton de inicio de session. Estoy utilizando Patron BLoC.

Intente llamar el metodo dispose() de mi bloc pero al intentar llenar el formulario nuevamente no guarda nada porque los streams fueron desechados. Solo quiero limpiar el flujo de datos.. algo como reiniciarlos y ya.

aqui parte de mi login_bloc.dart

```dart
  final _emailController    = BehaviorSubject<String>();
  final _passwordController = BehaviorSubject<String>();

  Stream<String> get emailStream     => _emailController.stream.transform( validateEmail ); // Los StreamTransform estan en Validators
  Stream<String> get passwordStream  => _passwordController.stream.transform( validatePassword );

  // Verificar combinacion de streams con los transforms implementados
  Stream<bool> get formValidStream => CombineLatestStream.combine2(emailStream, passwordStream, (e, p) => true);

  // Insertar valores al stream
  Function(String) get changeEmail     => _emailController.sink.add;
  Function(String) get changePassword  => _passwordController.sink.add;

  // Final Values
  String get email    => _emailController.value;
  String get password => _passwordController.value;

 // FUNCTIONS (Conectando con User Provider)
  Future<Map<String,dynamic>> login() async {

    Map resp = await userProvider.login(email: email, password: password);

     if(resp.containsKey('errors')){

      return resp['errors'];

    } else if (resp.containsKey('access_token')){

      return resp;

    } else {

      return { 'errors' : 'Ocurrio un error Inesperado'};
    }

  }


  void logout() async {
    userProvider.logout();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _emailController?.close();
    _passwordController?.close();
    loadingData?.close();
  }
```

y aca mi login_page.dart (solo el metodo donde llamo al LoginBloc.login())

```dart
_login( BuildContext context, LoginBloc bloc ) async {

    Map resp = await bloc.login();

    if( resp.containsKey('access_token') ) {

      Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
        context, 
        PageRouteBuilder(

          pageBuilder: (BuildContext context, Animation animation, Animation secondaryAnimation) {
            return HomePage();
          },

          transitionsBuilder: (BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation, Animation<double> secondaryAnimation, Widget child) {
            return SlideTransition(
              position: Tween<Offset>(
                begin: Offset(1.0, 0.0),
                end: Offset.zero,
              ).animate(animation),
              child: child,
            );
          },

          transitionDuration: Duration(seconds: 1)
        ),

        (Route route) => false

      );
    } else {

      List list = resp.values.toList();

      showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: Center(child: Text('Alerta')), 
            content: Container(
              height: 100.0,
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: list.length,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
                        // String key = resp.keys.elementAt(index);
                        print(index);
                        return Container(
                          child: Text(
                            list[index].toString(),
                            overflow: TextOverflow.visible,
                          ),
                        );
                      }
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              )
            ),
            actions: <Widget>[
              FlatButton(
                color: Colors.redAccent,

                onPressed: (){
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                }, 
                child: Text('Cerrar'))
            ],
          );
        }
      );

    }

  }
```

ahora el problema es que cuando cierro la sesión se mantienen los datos en los streams (el usuario y el password). lo que quiero es vaciar esos streams al cerrar la sesión

Comment: Agrega un poco de código para ver lo que está pasando.

Comment: en el login_page.dart llamo a mi bloc y le paso el context. Al primer inicio de sesion todo va de maravilla pero al cerrar la sesion y volver al login se mantiene activo el boton de inicio y puedo entrar pulsando sin rellenar los Textfields...

Answer (score 1):

Con el metodo dispose de mi bloc cerraba los streams pero no podia inicarlos de nuevo.

El problema era que estaba utilizando un provider desde MaterialApp... y solo se iniciaba una vez. Entonces al ejecutar el dispose de mi bloc no volvia a cargar y no podia utilizar los streams nuevamente